# How can I fix Apple Photos face locations?

Tags: photos.app

For the last few weeks I've been going through my Photos library, setting up faces data. Some data was already set back in the iPhoto days, but I've found a few photos with faces set, but the coordinates within the face are incorrect. Here's an example.

[image]

That's not a manually set face, but one that was recognized by the software. It is in fact Melanie, but obviously, the location is completely wrong.

I've also tried to ignore the incorrect location and manually add a face, but the manually added face moves to the same location after I drag it to the correct location.

[image]

Has anyone come across the problem before and knows how to fix it?

MacBook Pro 15-inch 2016
macOS 10.13
Photos 3.0